# Alternative to presto with fallback mechanism

Tags: presto

I am using presto as querying layer over cassandra for various aggregations but facing an issue where if the node goes down or timeout occurs for some reason, the running query fails. I need to have some kind of fallback mechanism.

Is there any alternative to presto with which i can implement fallback mechanism or if there's any way to implement it in presto itself.

Comment: Is this about interactive queries or scheduled jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Some vendors like Qubole have implemented a [retry mechanism](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/engines/presto/presto-query-retry.html) for specifically these kind of issues (which are more visible in the cloud, especially if you use [spot nodes on AWS](https://www.qubole.com/blog/spot-nodes-in-presto-on-qubole/) or pre-emptible VMs on GCP.

Note : This works only with [Qubole's Managed Presto Service](https://www.qubole.com/developers/presto-on-qubole/). 
Disclaimer: I work for Qubole